# Using HTML page as watch face on android wear smartwatch

Tags: android, html, wear-os, watch-face-api

I'm currently working on development of custom watch faces for android wear. I have one question, Is it possible to use HTML page as watch face on android wear? I'm trying to design watch faces using HTML and display them on android wear smartwatch.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not possible. [Android Wear doesn't include the `webkit` API](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/index.html), so it's unlikely that you'd be able to render your HTML content on the watch at all, which pretty well precludes using it as a watch face.

Given that, the only possibilities which occur to me are:

- You might be able to use a third-party `WebView` replacement, and build from that. The only one I know of is [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/android.html), and it's more about building a full app, so I don't know if it'd be possible to use in a watch face. There might be other options as well, but generally Google's `WebView` works well enough that I doubt there are many full replacements.
- You *could* render your `WebView` on the handset, grab a `Bitmap` of it, send that to the watch, and show it in a watch face. I can tell you from a experience that this is seriously nontrivial, and comes with some big caveats (like lag, battery use, and a connectivity requirement).

One caveat: it's pretty hard to **definitively** say anything is "not possible"; there may well be a way to do this that I'm not aware of.